# How to use malloc on a 2D integer array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

How do I define a 2D array where the first dimension is already defined with MAX_VALUES. I wish to be able to allocate memory to the second dimension. Below is what I have attempted. I want an array with A[1000][mallocd]

```
#define MAX_VALUES 1000
int
main(){
    int n= 10;
    int *A[MAX_VALUES] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

}
```

Comment: Your `A` has the wrong type, the `*` binds to the left. You want `int (*A)[MAX_VALUES]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int (*A)[n] = malloc(MAX_VALUES * sizeof(*A));
```

It will allocate contiguous 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
int*A[MAX_VALUES],n;
for(i=0;i<MAX_VALUES;i++)
  A[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int);
```

It will have MAX_VALUE rows with number of coloumns mallocked.

Comment: This doesn't allocate a 2D array but several separate arrays. @haccks answer gives the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

`int *A[MAX_VALUES]` is an array of `int` pointers, which is already statically allocated. If you want to allocate some space pointed by *each* one of the pointers you will have to iterate on the array and assign each pointer with a different `malloc`. Otherwise you will have to redefine your `A` (as @haccks answer is suggesting, for example).